# Xamarin.Forms ScrollView scroll programatically based on TouchEffect

Tags: xamarin.forms, scroll, scrollview, touch-event

I tries to programmatically scroll `ScrollView` based on `TouchEffect`, but when I do that it scrolls not properly, it scrolls instead of up it scrolls down and instead of down - up ...

Also from some point it stop scrolling ...

Here is code that I use to scroll programmatically:

```cs
            TouchEffect touchEffect = new TouchEffect();
            touchEffect.TouchAction += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                await Scroller.ScrollToAsync(args.Location.X, args.Location.Y, true);
            };
            Scroller.Effects.Add(touchEffect);
```

Comment: Could you provide more details about the `TouchEffect ` ?

Comment: I used the `TouchEffect` in the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/touch-tracking#the-touch-tracking-effect-implementations And test with `ScrollView`. I cannot reproduce the error. We need more information.